# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined > at xxxxxxx.push../src/app/xxxx-area/xxxx/xxxx.component.ts.xxxx.toggleVideo

Tags: angular, typescript, video, slider

I want to stop video when I go in `next` slider or `prev` slider. I'm using mat-carousel-slide. Code is like below

```
 <mat-carousel-slide #matCarouselSlide *ngFor="let slide of video; let i = index"
              overlayColor="#00000040" [hideOverlay]="false">

              <video *ngIf="slide?.Video" controls class="videostyle" id="videoPlayer">
                <source src="{{slide?.Video}}" type="video/mp4">
                Browser not supported
              </video>
            </mat-carousel-slide>
            <br>
          </mat-carousel>
          <button (click)="toggleVideo()">Play/Pause</button>
```

.ts code

```
  @ViewChild("videoPlayer") videoplayer: ElementRef;
  toggleVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();
  }
```

Please can you share with me any idea? How to stop video? This code show error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
> at xxxxxxx.push../src/app/xxxx-area/xxxx/xxxx.component.ts.xxxx.toggleVideo
> (xxxx.component.ts:87)

Comment: You're missing the `videoPlayer` template reference variable: `<video #videoPlayer *ngIf="slide?.Video" controls class="videostyle" id="videoPlayer">`. Also note if the `*ngIf` condition fails the element will not be present in the DOM.

Comment: I changed it. Doesn't show any error in console, and doesn't function. This     `console.log(this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause())` show `undefined`